# Redux saga API call returns undefined when fetching data from react native mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, react-native, es6-promise, redux-saga

I've been struggling with this for the past hour. I can't get it to work. In my saga I have a simple call to get some data from local mongo  database for react native (https://github.com/smartdemocracy/react-native-local-mongodb) and then dispatch it with put().

```
let day  = yield call(getDay, payload.day.date);
yield  put({ type: 'UPDATE_DAY', payload:{day:payload.day,index:payload.index,} })
```

This is the API call I make :

```
return db.findOne({ _id: date }, function (err, doc) {
   return doc;
});
```

It's my understanding that the call function expects a returned Promise, but I'm not even sure if what I have is really one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have your saga like this :

```js
let day  = yield call(getDay, payload.day.date);
yield  put({ type: 'UPDATE_DAY', payload:{day:payload.day,index:payload.index,} })
```

Then we'll create a function `getDay` that could be like

```js
const getDay = (date) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.findOne({ _id: date , function (err, doc) {
       if(err) reject(err)
       else resolve(doc)
    })
  }
}
```

As you can see we just wrap our function in a Promise, and use resolve/reject to get the result of the yield call.

For the record, you should wrap your yield in a `try/catch`, and in case the reject is triggered it would run the `catch` section